# AttributeError: 'Alien' object has no attribute 'image'(I am calling for a Group object)

Tags: python, pygame

Using a book to learn how to make a simple pygame Alien Invasion.I got to the part,where alien fleet needs to be drawn,but when I am trying to draw the whole fleet on x-level with asking for a Group object,it gives me the error(Full Traceback):

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "alien_invasion.py", line 35, in <module>

   run_game()

File "alien_invasion.py", line 34, in run_game

gf.update_screen(our_settings,screen,ship,bullets,aliens)

File "C:\Users\root\Desktop\python_work\alien_invasion\game_functions.py", line 53, in update_screen

aliens.draw(screen) #Make the drawn screen visible

File "C:\Users\root\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-
packages\pygame\sprite.py", line 476, in draw

self.spritedict[spr] = surface_blit(spr.image, spr.rect)

AttributeError: 'Alien' object has no attribute 'image'
```

I dont really think that error is  in that line of code,thats why I checked the whole code up,but even after sitting with it for more than an hour,I couldn`t find any errors,that would lead to such error.Attributes are distrabuted correctly,everything else is working in order,except this line.
Hope you to help.Providing as much I think is needed to understand the code and which can be related to the error.

```
import pygame
from pygame.sprite import Group
...
import game_functions as gf
from alien import Alien

def run_game():
...
    pygame.init()
    our_settings = Settings()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((our_settings.screen_width , 
    our_settings.screen_high))
    pygame.display.set_caption('Alien Invasion')

    ship = Ship(our_settings,screen)
    bullets = Group()
    aliens = Group()

    gf.create_fleet(our_settings,screen,aliens)
    while True:
        gf.ckeck_events(our_settings,screen,ship,bullets)
        ship.cotinuos_update() #updates ship`s position through each passing
        gf.update_bullets(bullets)
        gf.update_screen(our_settings,screen,ship,bullets,aliens)
run_game()
...
```

game_functions.py:

```
...
import pygame
from alien import Alien
...
def update_screen(our_settings,screen,ship,bullets,aliens):
    '''Updates images at the display.'''
    #Redraw the screen each time
    #Value of the background(red,green,blue)
    screen.fill(our_settings.screen_color)
    #Redraw all bullets before the ship and aliens
    for bullet in bullets.sprites():
        bullet.draw_bullet()
    #Crate ship on the background
    ship.draw()
    aliens.draw(screen)                #ERROR HERE!!!
    #Make the drawn screen visible
    pygame.display.flip()
...
def create_fleet(our_settings,screen,aliens):
    '''Create fleet of aliens'''
    alien = Alien(our_settings,screen)
    alien_width = alien.rectangle_alien.width
    x_we_can_use = our_settings.screen_width - (2 * alien_width)
    #at the left and at the right we have empy space = 2 aliens width
    alien_in_row = int(x_we_can_use / (2 * alien_width))
    #each alien has empty space with the size of 1 alien
    for number_of_the_alien in range(alien_in_row):
        alien = Alien(our_settings,screen)
        alien.x = alien_width + 2*alien_width * number_of_the_alien
        alien.rectangle_alien.x = alien.x
        aliens.add(alien)
...
```

If needed,
alien.py:

```
...
import pygame
from pygame.sprite import Sprite

class Alien(Sprite):
    '''Defines the single alien of the fleet'''
    def __init__(self,our_settings,screen):
        '''Initialize alien and create the starting position'''
        super().__init__()
        self.our_settings = our_settings
        self.screen = screen 

        #Create the image of the alien and make him rect.
        self.alien_image = pygame.image.load('images/alien.bmp')
        self.rectangle_alien = self.alien_image.get_rect()

        #New alien near top left of the screen
        self.rectangle_alien.x = self.rectangle_alien.width
        self.rectangle_alien.y = self.rectangle_alien.height

        #Store exact postiion
        self.x = float(self.rectangle_alien.x)

     def create_alien(self):
        '''Draw the alien at the current location'''
        self.screen.blit(self.alien_image, self.rectangle_alien)
```

Everything else should be in order,because I didn`t change anything there from the last time when I created 1 alien.
I expect to see just a fleet of alien at the top x-line for now,but it's just now working and give an error.

I am new to stack overflow,that's why there may be some inconviniences in the post.Sorry for that.Tried to do everything at my best.Already sitting there for an hour :O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from your `Alien` class:

```
self.alien_image = pygame.image.load('images/alien.bmp')
```

The `draw()` method expects you to have set a `image` attribute, but you named it `alien_image` instead. Try replacing this line by:

```
self.image = pygame.image.load('images/alien.bmp')
```

EDIT :

You also have a similar problem with the `rectangle` attribute: you named it `rectangle_alien`. Replace all your `self.rectangle_alien` by `self.rectangle` in your `Alien` class.

Comment: AttributeError: 'Alien' object has no attribute 'rect'  .Seems to work,but there is another error :/.Can you help me?Also,if it is not hard for you,can you tell me when i should specifically look for names?There was the same mistake with "update" earlier.When i should write specific names?

Comment: @EndOfTheGlory I edited my answer, I am not very familiar with `pygame` but I think `image` and `rectangle` are the 2 attributes that you should not rename in your `Sprite` classes.

Comment: WOW!It worked!Finally!Thank you.You really helped me)